# TaskStackbuilder API's

Tags: android

From [`TaskStackBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html#addParentStack(android.app.Activity)) API what is the difference in these 3 methods ?

1. `public TaskStackBuilder addParentStack (Activity sourceActivity)`
2. `public TaskStackBuilder addParentStack (ComponentName sourceActivityName)`.
3. `public TaskStackBuilder addParentStack (Class<?> sourceActivityClass)`

All of these methods add the Parent Activity So what would be the difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `TaskStackBuilder#addParentStack()` has been overloaded for convenience.

When the parent stack that you're interested in building, belongs to the current `Activity` or the activity that belongs to the current `Fragment` itself, you would use

```java
TaskStackBuilder#addParentStack(this); // OR
TaskStackBuilder#addParentStack(getActivity());
```

If the source activity class is different than the one building the stack, you would use the version that takes the activity class explicitly

```java
TaskStackBuilder#addParentStack(DetailsActivity.class);
```

Finally, if the parent stack is required for an activity not known at compile time i.e. the source activity component is only known at runtime, you would use

```java
// configured at runtime
ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("some.other.app", "some.other.app.Activity");

// build the parent stack for the dynamic activity component
tsb.addParentStack(cName);
```

The application package and the activity class names would obviously not be static strings. I've used them only as an example.